# How to fix this Synchronization issue between IOS app and PHP script (You are not allowed to access this page)?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

So in my IOS app I send data to my PHP script using this code:

```
NSString *RequeteIdsPayments = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                        @"idUser=%ld&BdAss=%@&typeReq=%@",(long)Userid,UserBdAsso,@"GetIdsMaintenances"];

        NSData *RequeteIdsPaymentsData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [RequeteIdsPayments UTF8String] length: [RequeteIdsPayments length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *requeteIdsites = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://wwww.exemple.com/Synchronisation.php"]];

        [requeteIdsites setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

        [requeteIdsites setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

        [requeteIdsites setHTTPBody: RequeteIdsPaymentsData];

        NSData *requeteIdsitesreturnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: requeteIdsites returningResponse: nil error: nil];

        NSString *responseIdPayments = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requeteIdsitesreturnData bytes] length:[requeteIdsitesreturnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

In my PHP Script I have something like this :

```
$typeReq = $_POST['typeReq'];

if ($typeReq == "GetIdsMaintenances")
    {
        $UserID = $_POST['idUser'];

        $requeteSelect = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
                            WHERE theID = '$UserID'";
        if ( $res = mysqli_query($connexion,$requeteSelect) )
            {
                while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat)) { 
                $ListeIDs[]  = $line['Id'];
            } 

            $FinalTable[] = count($ListeIDs);
            $FinalTable[] = $ListeIDs;
            // Send the Data
            echo json_encode($tableauFinal);    
                exit();
            }
         else
            {
                echo("Error: ".mysqli_error($connexion));
                exit();
            }
    }
```

The problem is the data that my IOS app receives is not what it is retreived form my db table but instead it receives an error from webserver :

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Forbidden [403]</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="100%">
<tr><td><font size="6"><b>403 Forbidden</b></font></td>
<td>
<p align="right"><a href="http://www.servage.net/" target="_black">
<img border="0" src="http://www.servage.net/img/content-logo.gif"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
You are not allowed to access this page. Possible problems:<ul>
  <li>Missing index file</li>
  <li>Misconfigured mod_rewrite settings in .htaccess</li>
  <li>Authentication Failure</li>
  <li>Incorrect file or folder permissions</li>
</ul>
<P>
<HR>
<ADDRESS><a href="http://www.servage.net/" target="_black">Servage.net</a> Clustered Webhosting running enhanced Apache Webserver</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Although the PHP script does not require authentification to access it, and the file containing the script is given all permissions (777). Where is this problem coming from and how can it be fixed?

Comment: $typeReq = $_POST['$typeReq']; should be $typeReq = $_POST['typeReq'];. I guess you are requesting the wrong URL.

Comment: It is just a mistype, I have it correct in my script

Comment: I re-checked the URL and it is the correct one.

Comment: Can you access this URL via browser?

Comment: Yes I can access it.